# C++ hover documentation, autocomplete extension for Visual Studio Code (like Python's "Kite")

Tags: windows, c++, visual-studio-code

Is there any extension for Visual Studio Code that supports C++ that shows the following?

1. Smart completions
2. Popular patterns
3. Code examples
4. Documentation

I am mainly interested in seeing the Documentation of a function when I hover on it.

---

Kite does this but unfortunately, it is available only for python:

> [Kite](https://kite.com/) is a cloud-powered copilot that boosts your programming
>   environment.

Comment: Microsoft has a preview of an [extension for C/C++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools). It only covers a small part of the features you are looking for and it has some bugs, but it's a start.

Comment: @mnme thanks. Is there any other extension because I have already installed that one.